# Rename files in Powershell deleting everything after "_"

Tags: file, powershell, file-rename

I am renaming several hundred files, all which vary with an item ID and then a bunch of text after. For example...

```
BBAT300_abcdefg.xls
BBAT400_abcdefg.xls
```

I need to delete everything from the underscore, and including the underscore on, so the result is this:

```
BBAT300.xls
BBAT400.xls
```

I found this bit of code earlier...

```
Get-ChildItem -Name -Filter *.xls | foreach {[Regex]::Match($_,"^[^_]*").Value}
```

and it appears to work, but I can't get it to actually rename the files. My knowledge of scripting is little to none, so this may be an easy fix, I just can't seem to find it. Powershell will show the results in powershell, but not actually rename the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pipe this line to the rename item command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt | Foreach-Object -Process { 
    $NewName = [Regex]::Match($_.Name,"^[^_]*").Value + '.txt'
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
}
```

EDIT: Changed it to support any location

Answer (score 0):

```
gci *.txt -Recurse -Force  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Rename-Item -NewName {($_.name.SubString(0, $_.name.LastIndexOf('_')) + $_.extension)}
```

Comment: you can use `$_.FullName.LastIndexOf('_')` to avoid the need to append the extension